# Filezilla Server and Client Port 21 enabled?

Tags: ftp, port, filezilla

I wanted to ask if it's enough when I enable the Port 21 on the Filezilla Server or if I also need to enable Port 21 on Filezilla Client?

I set up Filezilla Server on my PC, added a User group with a password (so that the client can connect), but I can't connect because I get an error. I deactivated the Firewall and now I'm trying to enable the Port 21, but I wonder if the Port also needs to be unlocked on the Client.

My goal with Filezilla client and server was send files automated with FTP but also that the Filezilla client is able to receive files but not send or upload any.

Comment: FTP is legacy protocol that requires two connections between client and server , a command and a data connection. And in the original form the protocol required the server to connect back to the client for the data connection. That required an open port on the client. That is still supported, but nobody uses that. Instead passive FTP was developed where the client established both command and data connections. The client can then PUT files on the servers and GET files from the server. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the FTP ports?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215066/what-are-the-ftp-ports)

Comment: This rant: [FTP Must Die](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie), paragraphs 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so when i understood it right. I would need to enable Port 21 for FTP, 22 for SFTP and 20 for the data transfer (using active ftp). Now what I'm not understanding is, that when using passive ftp it uses ports equal or greater than 1024, would i just then need to enable all port from the range of 1024-65535? Isn't this a insecure way when enabling every port?

Comment: Normally in an intelligent firewall when you allow FTP you need to open the port for the control connection, TCP 21 and then, in the clear text FTP protocol, the firewall can scan for and detect the PORT response. An FTP helper module in the firewall will then automatically open up the specific port number that gets assigned by the FTP server to that specific client, allowing for quite granular access control. - see https://serverfault.com/a/979257/37681